# List of jars Jetty-8 scans

Tags: jar, jetty, metadata

I am using a Java Application that runs on Jetty-8.

Is there any ways to have the lists of all jars that Jetty scans..

Can we print something (like jar's name or something) when jetty executes those jars.

**update**

The core issue is jetty-8 slow startup. 
I already added  `metadata-complete="true"`, and startup time has decreased.

But the problem here is to validate this concept

```
"metadata tag skips scanning jars of our web application."
```

Just to do an experiment I have made following changes :

**Try 1 :**

1. Removed All meta data tag from `web.xml`
2. Jetty log level mode changed to DEBUG.

What I have found in debug level logs is its scanning all jars of my web application. [ That is OK]

Then,

3. Added metadata tag and restarted server and found it is processing same means its scanning the jars of my web application.

Here I am looking for the ways that make sure that `metadata tag` is skipping scanning jars from my web application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command

```
java -jar start.jar --dry-run
```

lists all the dependency jars with classpath.

```
java -jar start.jar --help
```

gives you detailed usage of start.jar

Answer (score 0):

> Note: [Jetty 8 is EOL](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) (End of Life).  You are strongly encourage to upgrade.

The `metadata-complete="true"` attribute on the `WEB-INF/web.xml` does not prevent JAR scanning.

It merely states that the metadata is complete, and should not be modified, as a result of scanning for other metadata sources (like web fragments, class annotations, etc.)

However, there are other features of the Servlet Spec that are not metadata related, and require jar/class scanning to even function.  See  [`javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) and its [`@HandlesTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/HandlesTypes.html) annotation for an example.

If you were using Jetty 9, then you could control the list of jars that are scanned.